# PHP : Echo a file content as in "different" filename?

Tags: php, echo, file-get-contents

In PHP, i'm reading off a file, and then echoing it back. Like:

**rss.php**

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: x-requested-with, Content-Type, origin, authorization, accept, client-security-token");
header('Content-Type: application/xml');

echo file_get_contents('../../../news.rss');
```

But then when i access this `rss.php` file via browser, it gives the correct RSS file contents **but the file name is still "rss.php"**.

**I need it to be downloaded as "news.rss" filename.**

Any suggestions please?

(Please let's forget about why i don't directly access the "news.rss" file. There are some big stories behind.) Thanks all. :)

Answer (score 2):

try this, I am currently using this in my other program:

```
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=news.rss');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize('../../../news.rss');
readfile('../../../news.rss');
exit;
```

instead of echoing the contents, we use [readfile()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php) to read the file and output it to the output buffer.

**UPDATE:**

Please be informed that the above codes only download the file(no viewing). If you really want to show first the contents of the file, you may show it first then another link or make use of a button that "downloads" the file.

I also have the same program as you do. I have a viewing/updating of the file where the user can type, save it using fwrite(), then I have a button that download the file using the above code

Comment: But then i can't do any pre processing works before i output? I mean, you know, i have to do (append/modify/ etc) things with the original file `news.rss` before i echo it out.

Comment: You may want to have a link or button that do the above code. and name it "Download/Save". separate the viewing and the downloading